# XPages Open view and open XPage in edit mode

Tags: xpages

I've told a view to open using an XPage, but how do I open that XPage in edit mode?

Comment: Yes, you need to let people know which answers were the ones that were correct or helped you. If you don't several things will happen ... (1) people will not want to answer your questions and (2) people with similar questions will not know which answer was the correct one when researching their own question.  So, PLEASE help the community and go back and ACCEPT the correct answer on your previous questions.

Answer (score 4):

I will suggest that you buy and read the Mastering XPages book to learn the basics of handling views and documents in XPages. The book contains material that describes exactly what you are looking for (how to open an XPage in read and edit mode).

Answer (score 2):

I will assume your question relates to the XPage being used to open the selected document from the view and not the view itself as it is not possible to either define an XPage to to launch a view or for a view to be in "Edit Mode"...

1. When specifying the document data source for an XPage it is possible to define the default action as being Edit Document or Open Document. This sets the "action" property of the data source
2. The XPage itself has a "readonly" property that can be set to a specific value or computed. This is not tied to a specific data source.
3. It is possible to add a panel container control to the XPage and set the "readonly" property of the panel. This will allow all the controls inside the panel to be rendered as editable or readonly.

Answer (score 1):

views and xpages cannot be in edit mode, only document data sources can be in edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the readonly properties that Peter mentioned:
It is possible that a custom control got its own data source while the one from a parent (e.g. the xpage) is in edit mode. That's the mistake i make often while binding controls to data fields.